# Do Kryptonians possess psychic abilities?

Tags: dc, superman, psychic, powers

Kryptonians are noted for their incredible physical and mental abilities, due partly to their greater evolution, and partly to their adaptation to Krypton's harsher environment. More emphasis has been placed on their *physical* abilities than the *mental* however. In fact, it was outright stated in the New 52 *Superman* arc **Psi-War**  that he has no real or "notable" psychic or psionic power.

[image]

An overview of the story can be read here:
https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_Psi-War

This was somewhat contradicted in the comic itself when one villain plainly states he "drained Superman of his considerable brain power", seen here....
[image]

However..... this isn't the *only* contradiction.

As early as **Superman II** we saw examples of Superman using what could be considered psychic powers [the S-insignia projection, teleportation, mentally projected holograms]... but all of that *could* have been contributed to the Kryptonian *technology* in the space being used via mental control. The tech *has* been shown to react to and contain some psychic interface capability; this is the only logical way the A.I. could manifest the astral projections of Jor-El and Lara which then directly interacted with aspects ofthe fortress and Clark himself. However, if we want to disregard those instances, at the very end of the original cut of the film, Clark psychically removes Lois' memories of past events with a psionic "super kiss".... essentially an unstated form of "tactile telepathy."
[image]

Other forms of touch-based mental power actually have a canon basis in the Post-Crisis comics; both a great portion of Superman's invulnerability and his ability to keep objects together are attributed to a form of psionic ability called "Tactile telekinesis". This was largely used as the basis for the powers of the clone Superboy, Conner Kent, both Post-Crisis and New 52....

[image]

In certain regards, its also be attributed to how Superman flies...either "willing" himself through the air, or mentally controlling gravitons. Emphasis on strength being a form of "mental focus" can be seen on the wiki...

> His strength is more an act of conscious will on energy fields than actual physical strength. It is this act of conscious will that enables him to perform physical feats that are beyond the mere application force, such as moving a mountain top without said rock crumbling under its own mass.

Further to this, the wiki highlights aspects of his mental capacities, both trained and natural, which speak to a greater than human capacity, which could be an aspect of a psychic ability or training...

> **Indomitable Will:** Superman has shown to have a powerful spirit, free of corruption and temptation. Having been raised by a kindly Kansas farmer and his wife, he was taught to protect life and help others. He is very optimistic and never gives up, even when things look bad. Superman has *learned* how to place mental inhibitors on his own power so that he doesn't accidentally "flex and cause the tectonic plates to shift." To him, they are the barriers that allow him to feel human enough to live a healthy life, and he only ever releases one of them when fighting a particularly powerful opponent or performing a difficult task.

Of specific interest which could fall into the realm of "psychic training" are Superman's skills in 2 kryptonian martial arts.

**Torquasm Vo:**  a Kryptonian discipline that Superman uses sometimes. It is basically a means of **focusing ones mental discipline to help fight adverse effects such as mental domination.** It *can be used to manipulate someone's mind.* Superman used that ability during his fight against the Eradicator. It was used to **create an illusion** to let Superman enter inside the Eradicator.

**Torquasm Rao:** A heavy-hitting martial art from Krypton. Allows him to tap into his instincts and separate himself from his body. Makes him able to prevent others from manipulating his mind and **allows him to fight on the astral plane.**

We can presume it was either through one of these disciplines or his training with Jonn Jonezz that Superman developed the "series of psychic blocks" to defend his mind, blocks that Manchester Black---- a high-level metahuman telepath and telekinetic---- described as "the best I've seen". They prevented Black from delving into his mind at anything more than a surface level...and this was *post-Crisis* Superman.

By these definitions, it would seem clear that Superman obviously possesses some latent psionic capabilities... and this *would* make sense. With a highly developed and more evolved [and then solar powered] brain and neural structure, the likelihood or at least *potential* for psychic abilities would increase. Instances of this being the case can be seen in early comics....
[image]

Even looking at his enhanced **purely mental** faculties, the lines between "mega mind" and "psychic" are somewhat blurred. The following has been taken from http://theages.superman.nu/Encyclopaedia/entries/index.php?entry=powers:

> **Mental and Intellectual Powers**
>   Along with his other super-powers, Superman also possesses a super-intellect and other superhuman mental powers. 
>   In Spring 1940 Clark Kent exhibits the ability to temporarily halt the beating of his heart. In several occasions in subsequent years, Superman employs this unique ability in order to enable him to feign death.  Superman #21 alludes to Superman's having temporarily halted the beating of his heart and put himself into a state of suspended animation, and World's Finest Comics #54 cites Superman's ability to control his heart action in order to simulate the signs of death.
>
> In January 1941 Superman cures Lois Lane of her amnesia by means of hypnosis and a month later, as Clark Kent, he hypnotizes her into forgetting the super-feats he is about to perform so that he can rescue her from a burning cabin in his role as Clark Kent without betraying his dual identity.
>
> According to one text, Superman possesses a super-sensitive nerve structure, rendering him extraordinarily sensitive to the effects of cosmic disturbances.

There have *also* been instances of Clark using what would be termed "psychic powers", even if only under a yellow sun. This has accord across various media:

In the **Lois & Clark: The New Adventures of Superman** episodes *Through the Glass, Darkly* and *Battleground Earth* we see examples of [empowered] Kryptonians using a broadband type of telepathy [it's even plainly stated in the wiki that this is a normal ability.]

In the 1950s **Adventures of Superman** series, we see at least one instance of a Kryptonite-weakened Superman both *hypnotizing* Lois Lane **and levitating her** to get them and Jimmy out of a pit. It should be noted, however, that this was explicitly a **pre-crisis** version of Superman, where his powers could be added to at random. So...

**Main question:**
There is a difference between having a super powerful brain and mind, and having a mind capable of producing or utilizing psychic abilities, though the two *can* and often *are* linked. Given that Superman [modern continuity] has a super powerful brain, with everything shown above, is it logical to say he *also* has *some* level of psychic power, even if it's not as great as say, the Martian Manhunter?

If so, can anyone else provide evidence to support?

And if so, are these powers likely more a result of his natural Kryptonian neural structure, or perhaps from his training?

Comment: What comic is that "dimensional travel machine" from?

Comment: I feel that a big part of the OP could be an answer, with a tl;dr: It depends on the writer.

Comment: @Taladris agreed. Especially the entirely of silver age supes when he had whatever-power-is-needed-this-issue powers (super weaving, super mathematics [which is like regular math x 10, near as I can tell, which is hilarious], and super ventriloquism being key examples). I mean, what is super ventriloquism from outer space with no medium for sound waves to propagate but a psychic power? Irredeemable also essentially explains all the powers being rooted in reality-altering levels of psychic power rather well, tho it’s not canon.

Comment: @Broklynite: I don't know about super-mathematics, but there are indeed superalgebras: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Superalgebra

Comment: @Taladris  http://images.paxholley.net/blog/superman/supes_math1.jpg 20x16x10= 3,200 not 32,000

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt From “The Case of the Living Trophies” Superman #45 (1947)

Comment: @Taladris I wouldn;t _disagree_ with you here... but I thought it was worth being a fact-based discussion because, canonically, post-crisis, the only true "psionic" power it is **stated** that superman has is the tactile TK. I spoke to the "modern" superman here being a mix of post-crisis and New 52 [where the top picture was taken from]. That's also why i noted the contradiction; there are inferences of Kryptonian mental abilities in that comic, and Superboy **specifically** is mentioned with TK, but it's not been "stated" to be a natural or developed ability. Hence me wanting to discuss it.

Comment: @Russ Rainford.  Thanks, a little before my time.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt In truth, this was decades before MY time too, friend! I was just lucky to be exposed to a lot of the Golden Age stories because close friends and cousins were collectors, so I knew these stories existed. It was just a matter of finding them online as scans.

Comment: I've voted to close this. About 95% of the question should be a self-answer. In the face of all of this evidence, it's really quite hard to see what a decent answer would look like.

Comment: @Valorum This is why I said "There is a difference between having a super powerful brain and mind, and having a mind capable of producing or utilizing psychic abilities, though the two **can be and often are linked.** I was looking for **canonical evidence** that the _current_ Superman (well, any version, really, but most centrally current) _Does_ indisputably have **purely** mental powers. As you can see though, the data is so _All over the place,_ not to mention varying from version to version, that it's unclear. Are there any writers/ pages which **specifically STATE** he has mind powers?

Comment: @Russhiro - I'm not saying it's not a good question, just as written it's not clear why you've discounted the (multiple) examples in the question as potential answers.